# Xcode 7 beta made my apps storyboard files inaccessible

Tags: interface-builder, xib, xcode7

I installed the Xcode 7 beta 1 and it asked me to convert my code to Swift 2, which I did. All worked fine, there were only some problems with my apps test target. When that was solved, I built and ran the app and the error said: com.apple.interfacebuilder error 2001
I can't open the .xib and .storyboard files. It either won't open or Xcode crashes. What can I do?

Comment: Although it is no solution whatsoever I think it has to be noted that you shouldn't be using beta software with production environments/code without understanding the risks. That being said, I hope for your sake that you have a back-up of your code which you can restore and continue your work in the current stable version.

Comment: I got the same issue, impossible to open a storyboard on Xcode 7 beta. 
Even the default project one won't open.

Here is my crash log: http://cl.ly/110E3Y3P3E1U
Is it similar to yours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling Xcode 6 and unfortunately by changing Swift 2 elements back to Swift 1, I didn't back up. Then I deleted every Nib or Xib file in the project, but I did copy them separately in an other map. I could open these files, and copy and paste everything into new, replacing, Nib or Xib files of my project. 
I also had a problem with my test target, which I had to replace.
Hope this helps for other people having the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem with XCode 7 beta 4. Deleting the runtimes in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes fixed 2 problems for me: I can now open storyboard files again and all the simulators show up as targets again. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Bingo! This also started for me upgrading from Beta 3 to 4.

Answer (score 6):

> seancook
>   Jul 21, 2015 5:58 PM
>   (in response to zurb)
>   I experienced this, too, on El Capitan. NIBs wouldn't load, no Sims present, and unable to launch Simulators through the Xcode/Open Developer Tool/Simulator menu. After fighting it for a few hours I've finally got it working.
>
> Here's what worked for me (YMMV):
>
> I noticed a message in Console.app along the lines of the Simulator runtime not being code signed. I went to the path it described "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" and removed the runtimes that I had there. They were old runtimes, so I assume that some check in Xcode now applies that didn't previously. Who knows?
>
> After doing this, I could *finally* launch the Simulator via the Xcode/Open Developer Tool menu. Unfortunately, the Simulator still wasn't being shown as a run target in my workspace, so I kept spelunking...
>
> I then went into the Simulator's Hardware/Devices/Manage Devices menu and added a new iOS9 device. It didn't seem to do anything, so I quit out of Xcode and Simulator.app. I then re-started Simulator.app (via Xcode/ODT/Simulator) and lo and behold the expected iOS9 simulators were displayed.
>
> I closed and re-opened Xcode, changed the target OS for my project, and the Sims were finally displayed as run targets.
>
> HTH.

Solution from apple forum. This helped me!

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706

Answer (score 0):

It happens when installing XCode 7 betaX while the simulator is open (at least for me). Stopped all (I also deleted runtimes, following some suggestions here, not sure it helped) and restarted XCode.

Nib can be opened and Simulators came back.